# Can't resize canvas/scale using Fabric.js

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I need to display a large canvas as a smaller one for the purposes of good user interaction, but uploading a large canvas later. I am using Fabric.js and am trying the Canvas css trick where you set the width/height for the canvas in HTML and then set it via CSS to smaller one as documented here:

[fabric.js resize canvas to fit screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862356/fabric-js-resize-canvas-to-fit-screen)

When I attempt to resize as follows, it makes the canvas 300x150 (default canvas) and doesn't respect my CSS.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
        });

canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 1000;
```

CSS:

```
#c {
    width: 650px;
    height: 436px;
}
```

How can I adjust the "size" of the canvas the user interacts with while maintaining the "actual size" of the larger canvas via fabric.js? I am using bootstrap as well and am unsure if this would have any impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your javascript code with:

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {});  
    canvas.setWidth(1000) ;  
    canvas.setHeight(1000);
```

Comment: No such luck. It makes the canvas 1000px wide and doesn't respect the CSS

Comment: If you replace the CSS with `.canvas-container canvas {
    width: 650px;
    height: 436px;
}` it makes a difference ?

Comment: No, which has me wondering if this is an issue with bootstrap interfering

Comment: Adding !important to your width and height CSS properties fixes the issue, as can be shown in this minimal [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a93e88br/)

Comment: That did it! Thank you.

Comment: That's awkward since !important should block these properties and can't be overwritten anymore.

Comment: I had an error on my side, once I fixed that with the CSS being "saved", it worked!