# ProcessDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, fabricjs

We develop an app just that can overlay a png file (sticker) on a picture (like putting a mustache on the image selected and we can resize and rotate it, the problem is it only work on iOS, we keep getting this error on building or running it into an android platform.

This is the Error (ProcessDebugResources FAILED)

[image: ProcessDebugResources FAILED]

i hope anyone can help us, we search all over the net and in here, we tried every possible problem, and i saw earlier an answer because base on his problem it worked on android! here's what i found

[fabric.js resize canvas to fit screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862356/fabric-js-resize-canvas-to-fit-screen)

thank you in advance!

run it with stacktrace but honestly i don't know if this is the proper way to run it with --stacktrace.. [stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L78Y3.png)

Comment: can you run the build with --stacktrace and show us the output?

Comment: it's my first app and my first time doing it on ionic and angular, honestly i dont know how to run it on --stacktrace, but im trying it now..

Comment: see edit. :) thanks!